# Are there any tricks to quickly get find the eigensystem of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

Consider only 3x3 and 2x2 matrices.
Thank you.

Edited: some example matrices: \begin{matrix} 
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{matrix}

\begin{matrix} 
0 & 1 \\
2 & 1 
\end{matrix}

\begin{matrix} 
1 & 3 & -3\\
0 & 4 & -3\\ 
0 & 6 & -5\\
\end{matrix}

Comment: It depends on the types of matrices you're considering. You might like to add some examples of the kind of tricks you're talking about.

Comment: @Joppy edited with some examples.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: For contrived examples typical of exercises, it’s often worth looking at row/column sums or other simple linear combinations of rows/columns to tease out some eigenvectors and eigenvalues. You can always get the last eigenvalue “for free” by using the fact that the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace.

Answer (score 2):

The Eigenvalues are the roots of a polynomial of degree equal to the order of the matrix.

The case of degree $2$ is easy. The case of degree $3$ is harder in general (you don't learn the formulas for the cubics), but usually the exercises are arranged for easy roots (and you can use the Rational Roots theorem).

There are yet more complex formulas for degree $4$ and it has been proven that no formula exists for degree $5$ and above.

So very generally speaking, you cannot find the Eigen elements of a matrix without resorting to numerical (iterative) methods !